# Did Solomon worship pagan idols?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rabbis, avodah-zarah, melachim-kings-book-of, king-solomon

1 Kings 11:5-7 indicate that Solomon sought after the pagan gods. The Gemara states that these verses don't mean that Solomon himself worshipped idols, but rather that his wives did.

Is there any contextual, exegetical basis for the view that the Gemara gives?

Comment: In verse 8, it clearly states that his wifes did it: And likewise did he for all his foreign wives, who burnt incense and sacrificed to their gods. See also From David to Destruction, The Rise and Fall of Shlomo HaMelech, Shlomo HaMelech's Fall 5. Rashi, on this posuks cites Vayikra 19:17 stating that if you do not reprove someone that is sinning, you will bear his sin (Ralbag). That's why the Torah says that Shlomo HaMelech sought after pagan gods, since he did not reprove his wives.

Comment: @Shmuel -- If the Tanach meant that King Solomon worshipped idols himself, how would it have phrased it?

Comment: Exactly as it does now -And Shelomo did evil in the sight of the Lord- However, the Gemara says what I cited above. That he did not reprove his wifes in idolatry, thus it is considered as he did it himself.

Comment: Just as the Metzudas Dovid writes: וילך שלמה. על שלא מיחה בנשיו ההולכות, מעלה עליו הכתוב כאילו הלך אחריהם:

Comment: And, Yismach Moshe, Vaera 7

Comment: @Shmuel -- It says: "Solomon followed Ashtoreth the goddess of the Phoenicians, and Milcom the abomination of the Ammonites... At that time, Solomon built a shrine for Chemosh the abomination of Moab on the hill near Jerusalem, and one for Molech the abomination of the Ammonites."  If the Tanach meant that King Solomon really worshipped these idols himself, how else could it have phrased it?